# What happens when Memcached memory fills up?

Tags: cache, memcached

Hi I have a website running on Drupal and aws ec2 and rds.

So I installed memcached on this server and it's working. However I checked the statistics and found the cache is almost full and about 180mb is available.

Firstly I want to know what happens with memcached after memory allocated gets full?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the memory for a memcached instance gets filled it starts to remove data from the cache based on what has been least recently used. In other words it starts removing data from the cache, least recently used first and moving forward with more recent data until it clears enough space for newer data to be cached.